# PostgreSQL find duplicate field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like:

```
ID PERSON UPDATE
1   132  1.1.2015
1   132  2.1.2015
3   152  4.5.2013
9   152  1.2.2013
```

I need to count persons which have different id's which is greater than 1.

Comment: What are the results you want to get?  What have you tried?

Comment: Result of upper table to be: 152  2

Comment: If this table had a row `9 152 1.2.2014`, would the result still be 2 or would it be 3?

Comment: result would be still 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
select person, count(distinct id)
from t
group by person
having count(distinct id) > 1;
```

Comment: Needs to filter out `id = 1`.

Comment: @jpmc26 . . . Although perhaps not immediately obvious, the OP is trying to say "I need to count persons that have different ids".

Answer (score 0):

```
select person, count(*) from table
where id>1
group by person
```

or

```
select person, count(*) from table
where id<>1
group by person
```